# What is the place to store stringformat for bindings

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am having a list of string formats that I am going to use in all my forms.

```
Text="{Binding ADateTimeWithValue, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}"
```

Where do I store this const's ? I guess there is more than one way to do it, but I want it out of my forms and the binding syntax has to be as short as possible.

Maybe something like this:

```
Text="{Binding ADateTimeWithValue, StringFormat=local:Config.DateFormat}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may store all your formats in a resource dictionary:

```
<Window ... xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="DateFormat">dd-MM-yyyy</sys:String>
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ADateTime, StringFormat={StaticResource DateFormat}}"/>
    ...
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to use this one because the binding syntax is very short. But I am also going to have a code class with the const. please see answer from @Gusdor

Answer (score 1):

I tend to store them as compile time constants:

```
public static class FormatConstants
{
    public const string FORMATTER = "DD MM YYYY";
}
```

and reference like this:

```
{Binding Date, StringFormat={x:Static ns:FormatConstants.FORMATTER}}
```

**Why?**

This way we can reference our constants in both our views and our view models for consistent formatting across the application.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I just 'store' the formats in the actual `StringFormat` (as in your first example). I'm not sure what benefit you might get from storing them all in one external location, but it will make your code slightly less readable to anyone who doesn't know what all the formats are (eg. most people).

If you insist on doing this, then you could store them in the `Resources` section as a `string`:

```
<System:String x:Key="DateFormat">d MMMM yyyy</System:String>
```

Of course, you'd need to add the `System` xml namespace which is the `mscorlib` dll.

You could then access it like any `StaticResource`:

```
Text="{Binding ADateTimeWithValue, StringFormat={StaticResource DateFormat}}"
```